# Best way to smooth scrolling to an internal link

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, anchor, smoothing

I've searched and see lots of examples about this subject but I couldn't best way for me.

I'm just a bit familiar with JS and jQuery and I want to ask about smooth scrolling.

```
    <a name="urunler"></a>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#ppanjur" class="uruna">Plastik Panjur</a></li>
    <li><a href="#ipanjur" class="uruna">Alüminyum (İthal / Yalıtımlı) Panjur</a></li>
    <li><a href="#opanjur" class="uruna">Otomatik Panjur</a></li>
    </ul>
```

I've a navigation like this. This scrolls instatly. But I want to do it slowly. Which is the shortest & easiest way for this? I'm more familiar to JS and I don't want to download and use JS plugins.

1. I need to know full syntax with a click method for my links (they all have same class)
2. Should I remove href park from links?

Waiting for your help & still searching

EDIT!!!: In this situation, I need only one class. Is it possible to give this property for multiple classes?

```
    function scrollToElement (selector) {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(selector).offset().top
  }, 2000);    
};

$(document).on('click', 'a.uruna', function () {
    scrollToElement($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

I've got ('click', 'a.uruna', function (), how can I insert another class here or should I just write:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.uruna', function () {
    scrollToElement($(this).attr('href'));
});
$(document).on('click', 'a.new', function () {
    scrollToElement($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#ppanjur" class="uruna">Plastik Panjur</a></li>
    [...]
</ul>
```

JS:

```
function scrollToElement (selector) {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(selector).offset().top
  }, 2000);    
};

$(document).on('click', 'a.uruna', function () {
  scrollToElement($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

or

```
function scrollToElement (obj) {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: obj.offset().top
  }, 2000);    
};

$(document).on('click', 'a.uruna', function () {
  scrollToElement($(this));
});
```

Comment: couldn't use this code. Can you explain the <head> part or show with a demo?

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm sure your method will work but I think I have to import jQuery. I didn't know that, never work with it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6):

It can also be done in pure CSS using the following in your Style Sheet.

```
html{
   scroll-behavior: smooth
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that with JohnJohnGa's answer you get a "flicker" (at least for Google Chrome) where the page immediately pops to the anchor href position and back again before it scrolls there smoothly. This might not be noticeable with a fast computer, but it was definitely noticeable on the one I was working on. To get around this, I did the following:

```
$('a.page-scroll').bind('click', function(event) {
    var $anchor = $(this);
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
    }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
    event.preventDefault();
    window.history.pushState(null, null, $($anchor.attr('href')).selector);
});
```

Note, this prevents the default event from firing and then uses `window.history.pushState` to mimic it. For old browsers [that don't support pushState](http://caniuse.com/#search=pushstate) it will scroll to the correct location, but it just won't update the address location.

Answer (score -1):

Living demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wVEAy/2/

Note that for this case you would need to have an element with the same `id` as the one specified in the `href` tag of your link:

```
function scrollToElement (selector) {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(selector).offset().top
  }, 2000);    
};

$(document).on('click', 'a.uruna', function () {
    scrollToElement($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

Comment: thanks for your help. I think I had to import jquery for this. I didn't know that. As I said, I don't know much about JS and jQuery. Imported and it worked thanks.

Comment: what is the point here? trying to gain reputation by copy/paste answer from someone else?