# What script should i use to have smooth anchor scroll? None of my tried ones work

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, smoothing

I am trying to insert smooth scroll to anchor links in the same page script into my web, but that doesn't seem to work. I tried a few of them but none works...

Here are some of them which I tried:

[Best way to smooth scrolling to an internal link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18575084/best-way-to-smooth-scrolling-to-an-internal-link)

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/

[Smooth scrolling when clicking an anchor link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717527/jquery-smooth-scrolling-when-clicking-an-anchor-link)

http://www.sycha.com/jquery-smooth-scrolling-internal-anchor-links
http://www.ezmacwebdesign.com/Demo/smooth-scroll.html

Maybe I am doing something wrong? I am inserting these scripts to the `<head>` part in between `<script> </script>`, I am very new to this and I know almost nothing about js and jQuery...

I also have this script in my head section which sticks my header to the top while scrolling, maybe it is causing the trouble?

```
<script> $(function(){
        var stickyHeaderTop = $('#headertop').offset().top;

        $(window).scroll(function(){
                if( $(window).scrollTop() > stickyHeaderTop ) {
                        $('#headertop').css({position: 'fixed', top: '0px'});
                        $('#headeralias').css('display', 'block');
                } else {
                        $('#headertop').css({position: 'static', top: '0px'});
                        $('#headeralias').css('display', 'none');
                }
            });
        });
</script>
```

The link:

```
<a href="#vlog"> <div class="hbutton">Vlog</div> </a>
```

place where it should link to:

```
<a name="vlog" id="vlog"><div id="vlog"></div></a>
```

looking forward for help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you include the script required for scrolling as well?

If not, add this code also in your script tag along with your other js code and try:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
            var target = $(this.hash);
            target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
            if (target.length) {
                $('html,body').animate({
                    scrollTop: target.offset().top
                }, 1000);
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
});
```